# Fixed Input Group Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with bootstrap, because I need to leave static a search bar as shown below:

[image]

To do this I use the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</nav>  
<div class="list-page">
  <div class="row-search-bar">
    <div class="pos-rel">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
        <p>This is an element that is part of the list of results</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {  
  .list-page {
    padding-top: 24%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  } 
}

/* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { 
  .list-page {
    padding-top: 14%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }  
}

/*Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { 
  .list-page {
    padding-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
 }

/*Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { 
  .list-page {
    padding-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
 }

/*Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .list-page {
    padding-top: 6%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
 }

 .pos-rel{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
 }

 .row-search-bar{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color:red;
 }
```

The important part of my previous code is that it uses the property `position: relative;` in the `row-search-bar` css class, but when you move the content of the page, this search bar does not stay in place, it moves with the content. For the above, to achieve the goal of having the search bar stay in place, I use `position: fixed;` in the `row-search-bar` css class but this happens:

[image]

So what should I do to make the search bar stay in place when I scroll up / down and the search bar looks like this:

[image]

Many Thanks!

Comment: Try putting vertical-align:middle; on the label.

Comment: Do you need a fixed search form and how about the navbar? Is it also fixed?

Comment: @mahan Yes, both are fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `container-fluid fixed-top w-100` for the navbar and search form. Inside this container, use a container with two `rows`: one for the nav and one for the search form. Since you use `fixed-top`, you need to push down the other content of the body. Set padding-top of body to `160px` to do so. Height of this fixed container is `160px`. [Read more about why you need to so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664600/how-do-i-use-fixed-top-correctly-for-fixed-header-in-bootstrap4/50665288#50665288)

```css
body {
  padding-top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top w-100">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" 
                  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" 
                 aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRLXWM?

If you want full-width nav, move the navbar outside of the `container` and remove the padding of `container-fluid`.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top w-100 p-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdPMPv

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a problem with the `position: relative;` or the code.

I ran the same code and it seems to work fine for me.

[Have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/pranshudobhal/a5jyrnLv/)

The problem that you're facing is because you haven't included Bootstrap 4 files.

You might be using a Bootstrap 3 cdn which looks like `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`

I would advise you to change it to

`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do not answer my question. If you make this change in the code you will find my problem `.row-search-bar {position: fixed; }`